# Entity framework Core - Ambiguity over choosing Code First Approach and Database First Approach

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, ef-database-first

Choosing the Code First approach or the Database First approach with **Entity Framework Core** for my case is looking confusing from best approach point of view.

I have an existing database with some complex stored procedures.

1. If I choose the Database First approach, will it be good from performance point of view?
2. If I choose the Code First approach, can I map the existing Stored Procedures with Entities using Entity Framework Core? If this is possible, are there any disadvantages?

Answer (score 1):

We can't map them yet, but we can call them:

```
Public Class Sample
  Private Sub SpTest()
    Dim oContext As SchoolContext
    Dim oStudents As List(Of Student)

    oContext = New SchoolContext
    oStudents = oContext.Students.FromSql("GetStudents 'Bill'").ToList
  End Sub
End Class
```

There are some limitations:

- The Stored Procedure must return Entity data
- Magic String usage (although this can be averted by building a small API)
- Named parameters are not supported yet in EF Core (as of the writing of the article below)

You can find more info here:

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx

As to your performance question, I'd suggest doing some testing and benchmarking.

Comment: Was I able to answer your question(s)?

Comment: Yes. Your answer helped me

Comment: Very good, glad it helped. Would you consider marking it as the answer.